# How do I update a meteor app on amazon ec2 ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, meteor, upstart

I have a meteor app running on an ubuntu server. I'm trying to update the app by cd into the original clone and running `git pull` to get the latest from github.

I then run `meteor bundle ../bundle.tgz`
and then `cd ..` and `tar -zxvf bundle.tgz` to untar it.

The changes do not seem to be getting update. I even tried removing the original bundle completely and untaring it again. When I do that and try to access the site Nothing load and there is a 500 error saying that the script can't be found.

I'm using forever to keep my server running, Here is my updstart script:

```
# /etc/init/meteor.conf
start on (local-filesystem)
stop on shutdown

script

        cd /home/ubuntu
        export PORT=80 MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/meteor-tutorials ROOT_URL=http://www.ec2-54-211-152-59.compute-1.amazonaws.com
        exec forever start bundle/main.js

end script
```

When I initially uploaded the app I had to run `sudo service meteor start`.
How would I go about updating this app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use my install script, or look through its source and pick what you need. Sorry this isn't a detailed answer to your exact problem.

https://github.com/matb33/meteor-ec2-install